# Sony QX1 API support for bulb mode - needed for astrophotography

Tags: photo, sony, astronomy, sony-camera-api

The Sony QX1 camera would be fantastic for astrophotography - it's a very small and lightweight camera, but has a large sensor. However, for astrophoto the camera must be able to perform a few basic functions. One of these is Bulb Mode. Out of the box the QX1 does not seem to support Bulb Mode.

Is there a chance that Bulb Mode could be used via the API? I can't seem to find it in the docs. Even if it's not an "officially supported" setting, even if it voids the warranty. Is there any hack to enable it, at all? Firmware hack? "Magic" memory locations to overwrite to enable some kind of developer mode? Anything?

Another feature required for AP is a decent level of manual control, but that appears to be somewhat supported via API. At least ISO seems tweakable that way - let me know if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about a long exposure? This camera does not support that feature. Unfortunately if the functionality is not supported by the camera there will not be a way to activate this feature through the API.

Comment: Very disappointing. The QX1 hardware seems tailor-made for astrophotography in a lot of ways (front-mounted on an SCT astrograph it would not obstruct incoming light at all since it's so small). The A6000, also a relatively cheap camera, can do bulb mode just fine, but it's less of an all-around good match for AP due to bigger body size. I could be mistaken, but it seems almost like certain features are turned off arbitrarily on some models, even though the hardware could support them. I still hope bulb mode could be activated on QX1 via some firmware hack. Ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if the USB remotes work? There are two types on the other cameras e.g. A6000. First there is USB tehtering to apps like Capture One on Widnows and Mac or RCCDroid on Android. Other thing to try are wire remotes that too plug in the USB socket but use some extension pins that Sony added on their cameras.

I hope some of those work.

If I have to pick one to try I would go ot the USB tethering as it allows setting shutter speed to Bulb on other cameras e.g. A7ii. Also RCCDroid I believe had free version and simple USB cable with OTG will reveal if tethering works for QX1

PS You can do some rudimentary control from computer using gphoto2 over USB. The big drawback is that when you tether the camera it will not save files to SD card

PSS Sony indicate that QX1 is supporting "multi" mode on the USB hence simple wired remotes will work. Only problem is how to set the shutter speed to bulb and Camera Remote API does not allow that I believe.

PSS Does QX1 work without electronic lens? Other cameras require change of settings to enable shutter without lens

Comment: I've seen a comment from someone on a forum saying that the QX1 does work without an electronic lens.